# css drop down menu size and image issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm creating a css drop down menu with a image fixed under it. at the moment I'm having trouble getting the image to be the same size as the drop down menu and with getting the menu to be the size of the screen or fill the bar.any help will be greatly appreciated.

heres the css :

```css
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left; 
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;
    
                     
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:none;
}


#nav ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 

}
     
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; 
}
#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: blue;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#333;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">OUR COMMITMENT TO YOU</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">AUSTIN, TX</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ATLANTA, GA</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">SEATTLE, WA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PORTLAND, OR</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">PRODUCT</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">FEATURED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TOP RATED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HIS</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">HERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPRING CATALOG</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">THE ESSENTIALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SALES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   
<li>
            <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            </li>
<li>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24" src="https://montaviustech.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10.jpg" alt="death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10" width="absolute" height="" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what your looking for.

```css
#nav{
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left; 
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #333;                   
}

#nav li{
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;
}
#nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:none;
}


#nav ul{
    background:#fff; 
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0); 
    list-style:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px; 

}
     
#nav ul li{
    padding-top:1px; 
    float:none;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav ul a{
    white-space:nowrap; 
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
#nav li:hover ul{ 
    left:0; 
}
#nav li:hover a{ 
    background:#6b0c36;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: blue;
}
#nav li:hover ul a{ 
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover{ 
    background:#333;
}
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">OUR STORY</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">OUR COMMITMENT TO YOU</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">LOCATIONS</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">AUSTIN, TX</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ATLANTA, GA</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">SEATTLE, WA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PORTLAND, OR</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">PRODUCT</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">NEW ARRIVALS</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">FEATURED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TOP RATED</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HIS</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">HERS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ACCESSORIES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SPRING CATALOG</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">THE ESSENTIALS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SALES</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   
<li>
            <a href="#">BLOG</a>
            </li>
<li>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24" src="https://montaviustech.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10.jpg" alt="death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10" width="100%" height="" />
```

What i did was change the width of the image from absolute to 100%:

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24" src="https://montaviustech.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10.jpg" alt="death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10" width="absolute" height="" />
```

to

```
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-24" src="https://montaviustech.files.wordpress.com/2016/11/death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10.jpg" alt="death_to_stock_photography_vibrant-10-of-10" width="100%" height="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the width of the image to 100%. That will align menu-bar and image.